# Javascript alert instead of redirect in PHP mail script

Tags: php, javascript, email

Thanks to [Col. Shrapnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/col-shrapnel) I am using a VERY basic PHP script to send emails. The form is located [here](http://v2.ztmag.com/livedates.html).

This is the script:

```
<?php
mail('JBIRD1111@gmail.com','Live Date Submission',implode("\n\n",$_POST));
header("Location: thankyou.html");
?>
```

When a user submits the form, they are redirected to a thankyou.html page. I want to edit the code to display a javascript alert, instead of a redirect. I don't have much PHP knowledge, so how would I edit this code to return a alert instead of a redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you want to send a Javascript alert instead I would recommend using some basic [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) work. I would also take a look at the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) section of the documentation.

Otherwise you can inset some javascript in the original form page.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = "<script>alert('Thank you so very much! You rock!');</script>";
header("Location: originalformpage.html");
```

and on the original form page

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
{
    echo($_SESSION['message']);
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

Comment: I know Ajax is the proper way to do this, but I am looking for a quick and simple fix.  I added the code to mt email.php file and the bottom code to my form file, and I am not getting the alert. It is redirecting to the page, and sending the email, but no alert! 

Is this correct( below the form)

 <?php
        session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['message']))
{
    echo($_SESSION['message']);
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
?>

Comment: Correct, but make sure that the original form page has a .php extension on it.

Comment: I tried that....it says:  Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/jessechase/ztmag.com/v2/livedates.php:9) in /home/jessechase/ztmag.com/v2/livedates.php  on line 233

Comment: You need to put the `session_start();` at the very top of the file. Before anything else.

Comment: the alert shows up on page load, not after you submit. see it here:  http://v2.ztmag.com/livedates.php

Comment: Funny, it works for me. Doesn't show on initial load, shows up after I hit submit. Note that I didn't fill the form out at all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the header line with:

```
print("<script>alert('Thank you so very much! You rock!');</script>");
```

Not tested but should work.

Comment: It does work, howeverr, if redirects you to the email.php page (which is blank white) and then displays the alert. I am looking for the alert to display on the current page without loading another html file.